# prototype function doesn't work globally

Tags: javascript, function

I have a very simple version of the my code but the base logic runs the same. The problem is that I cannot use the map() unless I move it within the function I want to use it in. In the case below, the error I get is that .map is not a function, unless I move the map function in the func1().

Can I make it work without having to use it locally every time for various functions?

```
var obj = {
    val1: 1,
    func1: function(){
        var rndmVal = Math.random();
        var mappedVal = rndmval.map(0, 1, 0, 20);
        return mappedVal;
    } 
}

Number.prototype.map = function (in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) {
    return (this - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be locally defined. It just needs to be defined before it gets used. When/where is `obj.func1` being invoked?

Comment: Your code calls `rndmval.map()` but the variable that's initialized is `rndmVal`.

Comment: That's almost definitely just a typo in the question. Otherwise his error messages would be different, and it wouldn't work when `.map()` is defined locally.

Comment: @rockstar damn, you're right. didn't imagine it'd be that easy :/

Comment: @Pointy yup, that happens to be a typo :]

Comment: Is it a typo in your actual code or just in the posted question?

Comment: @Pointy that'd be the question.